# How to add event listener click() on <a></a> tag which got created dynamically

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How to add event listener click() on all  tag which got created dynamically.

I have a function which will add event listeners on all  tag once the page is loaded. But my UI will be updated with the new  tag when the user click on the button. So i would like to add click() function on the dynamically created  tag also. This has to happen irrespective of class name or ID.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("a");                               
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){                                                                  
   inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){                                                                                         
           //My code..                                                              
    });                           
 }
```

Comment: Add the event listener to the parent element you're adding the element to and then use event propogation to catch the event as it bubbles up.

Comment: Either `addEventListener` to your newly created element, or listen to all clicks of parent element and determine which child element was clicked there.

Comment: <a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("a");                               
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){                                                                  
   inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){                             console.log("foo")                                                                     });                           
 }//Use this code

Answer (score -1):

You can do such thing easily with jQuery:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>

<script>    
    $('#placeholder').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        // event handler for dynamically added children
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kr8ym0sa/3/

Comment: [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: I am not allowed to use jQuery. It will be really helpful if you can give your answer in javascript.